How can I strengthen the security in my Google account if I have been hacked?
I need more security measures for my Google account since hackers have been entering my accounts, regardless of whether I have 2-step authentication and a very secure password, also when this has happened, I do not receive notifications that someone entered to my account
I tried to use more safe paswords and 2FA
